# Develop on two computers

Tags: javascript, python, visual-studio-code

I have a computer at home (main) and a notebook (secondary). When I leave the house I like to program on my laptop. I would like to know if anyone knows any way that, when I save my file/progress (on the primary computer/even on the secondary), it is possible to continue where I left off previously. I don't need to upload it every time I'm doing it, using Google Drive.

I currently use Google Drive to upload from one computer and download from another. However, I would like it to be automatic in some way. No need to upload or download.

Comment: File sync apps will still need to upload to a server somewhere.  Microsoft OneDrive maybe?  Sync can go wrong so make sure to keep backups that are separate from your file sync method.

Comment: Personally, I'd use git - as a developer it's always good to have a history of changes. But then, that's not automatic, so ignore me :p

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use https://github.com/ for that. you can push your work to GitHub, and then pull it into another device. it still requires you to upload your program but it is better and easier than using Google Drive.

Comment: you don't need github, just set the other git repo as a possible remote, then push to the other git repo: `git push pc2 main`